# How to gzip a folder under a symlink

Tags: gzip, tar, symlink

I'm trying to gzip all subdirectories and files of a folder.The peculiarity is that the file that I compress is a symbolic link to the last release of my site

[image]

```
filename=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
cd /home/site
tar -zcvf $filename.tar.gz current/
scp $filename.tar.gz server:~/backups/production
rm $filename.tar.gz
```

When the operation ended and I open the compressed folder. I'm sying the symlink of the folder not its content. What's the wrong point ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. You need to specify the `-h` flag when creating the archive if you want to dereference symlinks. From the `tar` [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/dereference.html):

> Normally, when tar archives a symbolic link, it writes a block to the
>   archive naming the target of the link. In that way, the tar archive is
>   a faithful record of the file system contents. When `--dereference`
>   (`-h`) is used with `--create` (`-c`), tar archives the files symbolic
>   links point to, instead of the links themselves.

Comment: Should I write like that `-zchvf` or  `-zcvf -h`

Comment: @KubiRoazhon `-zchvf` is fine